# IIS is still serving up the old digital certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate, iis, ssl-certificate, iis-6

- Windows Server 2008 SP2, IIS 6

I have purchased a new wildcard digital certificate which I have installed in IIS via Site > Server Certificates:

[image]

and then updated the bindings for the website in question making sure the website is assigned the new certificate:

[image]

Restart the website and opening the website in multiple (Chrome, Opera etc.) browsers and I am still seeing the old certificate - the one expiring 26/02/2017.

What am I missing here? Surely I don't have to restart IIS to apply the new certificate?

FWIW I restarted IIS and am still seeing the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately this required a reboot to fix. Once rebooted I went to the above binding and had a look and it had the previous certificate still selected - **not** the one in the screenshot. I once again selected the new one and hey presto it worked.

So it appears that in this case IIS was confused and even though the GUI was showing the new certificate as selected it wasn't.

Comment: Can confirm, reboot was necessary for me too.